# How does backpropagation work in LSTMs?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, backpropagation

After reading a lot of articles (for instance, this one [Understanding LSTM Networks](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)), I know that the [long short-term memory (LSTM)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04069) is an artificial recurrent neural network (RNN) architecture used in the field of deep learning.

How does backpropagation work in the specific case of LSTMs?